# Knockout Components: Pass child components as parameter to parent component

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

We are refactoring a Knockout SPA. One of the improvements is to make components more generic where possible. For example, we would need a "polymorphic"/generic `<elements-widget>` that renders a list of elements. Depending of type of list, the type child components may vary.

**Sample for the current app**:

We have a "persons page":

```
<persons-page>
  <persons-widget> <persons-widget>
</persons-page>
```

The "persons-widget":

```
<div class="grid" data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <person-widget params="element:$rawData"></persons-widget>
</div>
```

**Instead we would like use the generic component** on the "persons page"

```
<elements-widget params="elements:elements, elemComponent:'person-widget'">
</elements-widget>
```

and the template of the generic component should look something like this:

```
<div class="grid" data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <elemComponent> params="element:$rawData"></elemComponent>
</div>
```

where *elemComponent* ist the parameter passed to the *elements-widget*.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) to control what exact component will be rendered in this place:

```
<div data-bind='component: {
    name: "shopping-cart",
    params: { mode: "detailed-list", items: productsList }
}'></div>
```

Component name, "shopping-cart" in this case, can be changed to the property of the current context object, say `elementType` containing the component name you want to render.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gonna try that soon!